# can anyone explain detailly this video(title: sensorless active complaince)

Tags: control, kinematics

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8Je93soOZE

i am interseted in how they achieve compilance and detect collision in servo without the use of sensors. so any one please explain briefly

Comment: those are servos moving the links ... the servos are controlled programmatically

Comment: please ask a specific question

Comment: my question is , how do they achieve compliance and detect collision in that servos without any sensors?

Comment: watch the video again ... sensors are being used

Comment: furthermore searching, I found that ,it is dynamixel servo which has current feedback system, which helps to calculate torque output of servo .  i think that , from that torque output graph , any collision is detected when an unexpected/sudden  rise or fall in torque in the torque vs time graph and the servos are stopped in their position  .    Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

It's explained on the video description:

> In this research, a methodology for sensor-less full body active
> compliance was used on a 6-DOF RSS (Rotary-Spherical-Spherical)
> parallel manipulator. The manipulator can detect and comply with the
> external forces on any part of its body without using any explicit
> force/torque sensor at the joint or the end-effector. This was done by
> utilizing the estimated joint torque based actuator current feedback
> only. A three-layer cascaded impedance controller for active
> compliance and reaction to various human interactions was used. The
> proposed design and unique methodology for compliance exhibits an
> effective and inexpensive yet reliable alternative to be used in safe
> human-robot interactions and force controlled manufacturing
> applications.

Collision / Compliant motion is detected by the current draw increase of the motor.

> This was done by utilizing the estimated joint torque based actuator
> current feedback only